# Writing items to a Oracle Database in Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, scrapy

I have a settings.py file and pipelines.py file in my scrapy project.
I would know how to write items that i have parsed to Oracle database.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy does not offer built-in support to export to Oracle or any other SQL engine.

However, it does make it easy for you to [write your own item pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline) to do so.

See also:

- [Scrapy / Python and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741945/scrapy-python-and-sql-server)
- [Writing items to a MySQL database in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845839/writing-items-to-a-mysql-database-in-scrapy)
- [Scrapy - How to crawl website & store data in Microsoft SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266482/scrapy-how-to-crawl-website-store-data-in-microsoft-sql-server-database)
- [Scrapy pipeline for MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022972/scrapy-pipeline-for-mssql)

Comment: I know, there are some libraries in python which help to us to connect directly to databases. And i did one for MySQL server. However it seems like not applicable to Oracle server

Comment: If you want to know how to connect to an Oracle database from Python, maybe you should remove Scrapy from the question.